# Error-Propoagation: Combine confidence intervals of two subsequent regressions

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, error-propagation

I have two subsequent regressions and want to combine the results of these two regressions. But I also want to show the increased uncertainty by somehow combining the confidence intervals of these two regressions, if this makes sense.

The first model is a linear regression (log-normal) to model the total volume of trees (ln(volume) ~ln(bhd)):

[image]

The second model is a linear regression (beta) to estimate which proportion of the tree volume is consisting of bark and wood (fraction_wood ~ ln(bhd)):

[image]

By multiplying the predicted volume with the predicted wood fraction, I want to achieve separate models for wood and bark volume each, something like this:

[image]

But how do I combine the confidence intervals aka the "uncertainties"? I suppose I should account for the uncertainties of both regressions? Can I calculate the confidence interval of the combined models with the standard errors of the fit like this:

```
upper: (volume_prediction + 2 * volume_se) * (fraction_prediction + 2 * fraction_se)
lower: (volume_prediction - 2 * volume_se) * (fraction_prediction - 2 * fraction_se)
```